# Are the entity-system and component-based tags describing the same thing?

Tags: discussion, questions, tags

We have these two tags: [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based).

I am under the (perhaps mistaken) impression that an entity system **is exactly the same thing as** a component-based system, and that they are two different names for a system which revolves around having entities which store a collection of components in the style described in [Evolve your Hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/).

**Is this true - are they exactly the same thing?** I've [suggested the tag synonym](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/component-based/synonyms), but I want to bring it up here to check that it is actually valid.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think all entity systems are component based. Common consensus at this point in time might be to steer people who are asking about non-component-based entity systems towards component based systems, but I wouldn't call them synonyms.

Comment: +1; and it works the other way too (one can have a system that is not an entity system but that is built upon the aggregation-based principles of component-oriented design).

Comment: That's enlightening then. Thankyou!