# Merge all the entity tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The following tags:

- [entity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity) (33 questions),
- [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) (316 questions),
- [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component) (68 questions)

(total of 350 questions) are all mostly about the [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) architecture.

Although [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) is the most popular and has the best wiki summary, I suggest merging them into a new tag: [entity-component-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component-system).

Comment: I wonder if there's value in `entity-system` versus `entity-component-system` though (where the distinction is that the first one is about entity systems that don't involve the currently in-vogue component-based model)? Is there another tag we could use to express that? Does it not really matter? My concern is mainly because *undoing* that merge later is much harder, so I'd rather we make sure we want to do this; if anybody has thoughts please post an answer.

Comment: (I agree that `entity` and `entity-component` are silly.)

Comment: @Kromster Is your intention to 'revive' the debate?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt My intention is to attract more attention to this question and make it done as proposed.

Comment: That said, there seems to be some argument for *some* tag change, here. If we come to any conclusion involving tag change, we should make the two related questions duplicates of this one, as one is an *obvious* duplicate, and the other is *older* but *appears contradictory to this question*.

Comment: @Gnemlock You're right, they're not duplicate, they're touching the same tags, but are not duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Do we need a new 'entity-component-system' tag?](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2233/40264) and [Are the entity-system and component-based tags describing the same thing?](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/802/40264).

Answer (score 5):

In reference to [Josh Petrie's comment](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/merge-all-the-entity-tags#comment5391_1961), I think [entity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity) is silly.

When referring to an entity in the context of an Entity-Component-System architecture, for instance, the role of the Entity is quite agreed upon.

So in the context of the tags [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component), we have a good idea of what the entity there will be used for.

But when we use `entity` by itself, what does it mean? What is its role?

IMHO, when it is used on its own, it's generally used in the context of a set of parameters and features that form a whole; I see it as a synonym of object, game object, agent, etc.

Used in that context, we already have the tag [gameobject](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameobject), which, IMHO, would be equivalent.

Thus I don't really see why we need to keep the tag `entity`.

**I think the questions that have the tag `entity` should be revised one by one, and re-tagged [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system), [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component) or `gameobject`, (or just removed) depending on the content of the question.**

Comment: And I don't really see what would [tag:entity-component] be about.

Comment: I would assume [tag:entity-component] is about either the individual components making up the entity, or an entity based component system.

Comment: @Gnemlock Would it be different than something tagged [tag:component-based]?

Comment: Possibly, in a broad sense, yes. The two are not mutual. Thats the main reason I am hesitant to the idea of using synonyms; that said, it might have a better *functional* impact, if we clarify that the two are *not* generally synonyms (and we just bundle them together for the purpose of questions) in the usage guideline.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with *Alexandre Vaillancourt*, in regards to the [entity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity) tag. However, I think we should discuss *all* tags within the scope; it seems redundant to make decisions on replacing a tag, when we are still discussing potential removal of the possible replacement tag.

I think a couple of the tags can be improved in order to assist usage, either through synonyms or usage clarification. I am going to bring up another tag, as I feel it works well as a potential synonym.

---

[component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based): [A previous question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/802/are-the-entity-system-and-component-based-tags-describing-the-same-thing) raised issues in regards to confusion with the correct usage, suggesting it as a synonym for [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system). I feel that the answer applies to this context, and highlights a common relation:

> I don't think all entity systems are component based. Common consensus at this point in time might be to steer people who are asking about non-component-based entity systems towards component based systems, but I wouldn't call them synonyms.
>   
>  <sub>[- *answered Apr 23 '12 at 14:14* by Tetrad♦](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/803/63208)</sub>

---

- [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system): I think we should keep this tag. However, we should amend the usage guidelines. The guideline should address the fact that entity systems are not always component based, and suggest *additional* use of the [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based) tag, if the user is specifically asking in context of a component based entity system.
- <del>[entity-component-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component-system)</del>: I do not think we should implement this tag. Between [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based), we have this covered. Furthermore, the two are not *necessarily* linked, so the single tag would not actually *replace* the two separate tags.
- [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component): I see this going one of two ways, but ultimately, I do not think we need this tag for the same reason we do not need the <del>[entity-component-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component-system)</del> tag. Given that the *context* appears to be specific to component-based entity systems, the questions using this tag should use the [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based) tags. I think it might be *easier* to simply merge the tag into [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) (specifically because it has more relevance to an entity system than a component-based system), but we should consider any potential to confuse users who note that we have the two as synonyms, and thus assume that they are synonyms *by definition* and not *by definition of how people are using the tags, themselves*.
- [entity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity): [As per *Alexandre Vaillancourt's* answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2327/63208), we should assess each question. Some questions appear more relevant to [gameobject](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameobject), in which case, they should be *re-tagged*. Ultimately, I feel this tag should be made a synonym of [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system), once the prior cleanup is complete.

---

*While we are on the subject*; I can find a couple more tags that *somewhat* fall into the context of this discussion. However, for the purpose of quality control, my stance is that we should clean up the tags *already discussed* before involving others. That said, when this reaches a resolution I am happy with, I might bring the other tags to the attention of meta, to ensure we are directing users and questions in the right place.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting [Tetrad's answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/803/40264) on the similarity between [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based) (or [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component)??):

> I don't think all entity systems are component based. Common consensus at this point in time might be to steer people who are asking about non-component-based entity systems towards component based systems, but I wouldn't call them synonyms.

And [Josh Petrie's answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2234/40264) on merging re-tagging questions that have a both [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component) or both [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based) into a new `entity-component-system`:

> Not all entity systems are component-based, and not all component-based code is an entity system.

**I don't think it would be wise to merge all of the three tags into a single `entity-component-system`.**

What we need is a better description for each tag.

I would have suggested to introduce a new tag `entity-component-system` (I already did :P), but, again, quoting ([myself](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/134070/40264)):

> Here is what an ECS is:
>
> [image]
>
> ([Image source](http://www.theblindelephant.com/the_blind_elephant_fable.html))
>
> By this, I mean that every dev and every company has its own view of what an ECS is or should be.

The tag would either be too specific or too broad. So I don't think we should introduce a new tag `entity-component-system` either.

Comment: I think the image makes the point confusing. The metaphor from the image does not really apply well to *humans*, given reasonable understanding in a programming environment. That said, I agree with not introducing *entity-component-system*, albeit for different reason.