# Do we need a new [entity-component-system] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I often see questions with both [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component) tags (or [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based)).

To make it a bit clearer, should these questions be tagged with a new [entity-component-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component-system)?

Comment: Prior discussions [here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/merge-all-the-entity-tags) and [here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/802/are-the-entity-system-and-component-based-tags-describing-the-same-thing).

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of questions that you feel would be able to be tagged better if they had one extra tag slot to use? I feel like most of the time questions at the maximum tag limit have quite a few pointless, bad, or redundant tags on them.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I edited the question :)

Answer (score 4):

I am still in support of [Tetrad's answer to this question back in 2012](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/803/1430). Not all entity systems are component-based, and not all component-based code is an entity system.

Today's "entity component system" is building heavily on component-based concepts that have been in place in software engineering for years, and I think there's value in continuing to allow the distinction between "I am asking about an entity system" ([entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system)), "I am asking about component-based programming or design ([component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based)) and "I am asking about both" (using both tags).

If anything I am in favor of correcting the description of [entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) and [entity-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-component) (the former is really describing the latter, which itself has no description at all), but otherwise doing nothing.

Comment: I don't think entity-component uses system. The way I see it, Unity is an [tag:entity-component] (and [tag:component-based]), it has no system, and the process is done in the components. The description of [tag:entity-system] fits what I've known as an entity-component-system...